# Flutter: how to use .addListener of TextEditingController

Tags: flutter

i'm building a simple app that prints the result of the current `TextFormField`. Such as when the text changes it prints the new value.

I found out that you can achieve this with `TextEditingController.addListener` that listens for changes and executes a function.

So i wrapped it all in initState as follows

```js
@override
  void initState() {
      addressController.addListener(() {
        print(addressController.text);
      });
```

The problem I have is that sometimes it records changes even when there aren't any:

This is what happens writing a word and then deleting it.

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Do you have .removeListener in code?

Comment: ehm ... where should I have it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you add listener then you should remove it somewhere, otherwise there can be situation when TextEditingController will have 2 or more listeners:

```
@override
void initState() {
    addressController.addListener(_addressControllerListener); 
    super.initState() 
}

void _addressControllerListener() {    
    print(addressController.text); 
}

@override 
void dispose() { 
   addressController.removeListener(_addressControllerListener); 
   super.dispose() 
}
```

Comment: very curious! thanks to share. dispose is most cool.